# Start Activity not working properly in this scenario?

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi every one in the below code after the image has been selected it is not moving to next activity ,in gallery if we select first item it remains in the same activity but we select another item other than first position image it is moving to next activity

`startActivity(mv);` the shown startactvity is not calling when we click on the first position image

but the toast is appearing as image has been selected but not moving to next activty

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

case R.id.imageView2:

            upLoadPhoto();

            break;
protected void upLoadPhoto() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

    }


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


 if (requestCode == 100 && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                System.out.println("in case");
                Uri _uri = data.getData();

                if (_uri != null) {
                    // User had pick an image.
                    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver()
                            .query(_uri,
                                    new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA },
                                    null, null, null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    // Link to the image
                    final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0);
                    Log.v("imageFilePath", imageFilePath);
                    File photos = new File(imageFilePath);
                    try {
                        gbmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                                new FileInputStream(photos), null, null);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    cursor.close();

                }
                mv = new Intent(Imageselection.this, Modeselection.class);
                mv.putExtra("test", gbmp);
                mv.putExtra("name", 100);
                System.out.println("going to gamestart class");
                startActivity(mv);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Comment: This error i got in Logcat. JavaBinder(11060): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!

Comment: I think I got your problem, please check my answer and see if it can solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Its because you passed the whole image to the bundle.

The bundle has limited Size, you cannnot put the image itself into the intent.

You need to save your image to a cache, then either pass the image's file name or file path to the  `putExtra` and then retrieve it later by accessing the filename or file path.

For your case, you select an image from gallery, then you can get the URI or path of that image, put the URI/path to the intent, and retrieve it on your another activity.

When you call an intent to launch the gallery, it will return with `data` which contains the selected file's Uri.

Here r some sample code you may need if you launch the default gallery:

```
// Launch Gallery to choose pic.
Intent intentLaunchGallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

startActivityForResult(intentLaunchGallery, LOAD_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

...

private String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

...

// Gallery launched to choose picture
if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            fileUri = data.getData();
            filePath = getPath(fileUri);
//              fileUri = Uri.parse(filePath);

            // call media scanner to refresh gallery
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(), new String[]{filePath}, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                    Log.i("MediaScanner", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("MediaScanner", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });

//              Toast.makeText(this, "Image chosen from: " + filePath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.d("MainMenu->onActivityResult", "Image chosen from: " + filePath);

            // display the picture chosen by user
            Intent intentShowMarkers = new Intent(MainMenuActivity.this, ShowMarkersActivity.class);

            intentShowMarkers.putExtra("IMG", filePath);   
            intentShowMarkers.putExtra("FLAG", false);

            MainMenuActivity.this.startActivity(intentShowMarkers);

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            // user pressed the cancel of gallery
            Toast.makeText(MainMenuActivity.this, "Cancelled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Note: passing large strings via putExtra() can also trigger the same exception (ie for anyone reading this fyi the exception is not specific to images)...

Answer (score 0):

try below code. for select an image from gallary

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
```

and in your `onActivityResult` method write below intent to go for next activity

```
Intent picIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,
                        NextActivity.class);
                picIntent.putExtra("gallery", filePath);
                startActivity(picIntent);
```

in your `NextActivity` class `onCreate` Method write below code

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        String fileString = getIntent().getStringExtra("gallery");


        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileString));
```

Comment: I already tried by calling startActivity(mv) below cursor.close() but it doesn't work.